# Size of the structure and addition of individual data type sizes mismatching

Tags: c, struct, size, sizeof, jna

I have the following structure. When I print the size of the structure using sizeof(ipj_tag_operation_report) I get the value 480. But when I try to add the individual size of each data type included in this structure, I only get 405. Also, if I add the sizes of data types, the "rssi" field value comes in 165th byte. But when I get this structure in JNA, when I iterate through the returned contents it is in 51st position of the array. Why are these mismatches? What am I doing wrong here? Please advice.

Below is my structure and its related structures. I have commented the size of the data types. These are values I found in the internet.

```
            typedef struct 
            {
                bool has_error; //1
                ipj_error error; //4
                bool has_tag; //1
                ipj_tag tag; //174
                bool has_tag_operation_type; //1
                ipj_tag_operation_type tag_operation_type; //4
                bool has_tag_operation_data; //1
                ipj_tag_operation_data_t tag_operation_data; //72
                bool has_retries; //1
                uint32_t retries; //4
                bool has_diagnostic; //1
                uint32_t diagnostic; //4
                bool has_timestamp; //1
                uint64_t timestamp; //8
                size_t lt_buffer_count; //8
                uint32_t lt_buffer[30]; //120
            } ipj_tag_operation_report;

 typedef uint32_t ipj_error;

            typedef struct 
            {
                bool has_epc; //1
                ipj_epc_t epc; //72
                bool has_tid; //1
                ipj_tid_t tid; //56
                bool has_pc; //1
                uint32_t pc; //4
                bool has_xpc; //1
                uint32_t xpc; //4
                bool has_crc; //1
                uint32_t crc; //4
                bool has_timestamp; //1
                uint64_t timestamp; //8
                bool has_rssi; //1
                int32_t rssi; //4
                bool has_phase; //1
                int32_t phase; //4
                bool has_channel; //1
                uint32_t channel; //4
                bool has_antenna; //1
                uint32_t antenna; //4
            } ipj_tag;

typedef uint32_t ipj_tag_operation_type;

            typedef struct 
            {
                size_t size;
                uint8_t bytes[64];
            } ipj_tag_operation_data_t;

 typedef unsigned __int64    size_t;
```

Comment: Padding, alginment, optimisation, and other reasons. There is no guarantee about a specific layout for many good reasons. DO not rely on that. If that is for serailisation, use correct code for field-wise store/restore.

Comment: @Ian: That is compiler specific and not part of the standard.

Comment: @Olaf I see... Do you mean some compilers won't have Pragma Pack? This is my first time knowing it. How do you get this info from?

Comment: "How do you get this info from" - Are you aware there is an [ISO standard for C](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)?

Comment: @Olaf I am new to C. I was using this C code in JNA. since I need the field info of RSSI I had to edit this code. Then only I saw this issue. Where do I start from? What does "field-wise store/restore" mean?

Comment: As @Olaf pointed out, size of struct in C is not necessarily the same as the sum of sizes of its fields. To enforce this, you'll need to mark the struct as "packed" which may be done differently in different compilers (as this feature is not standardized). For example, many compilers implement some form of `#pragma pack` directive.

Comment: @willcodeforf00d: Proper serialisation is the better approach. There are tools/libraries to support that. Some even parse `struct` definitions to generate proper (and standard compliant) offset-tables. Relying on a compiler-feature is often a bad idea. (and for packing the syntax might vary - for gcc `__attribute__` s are prefered).

Comment: @mayooran: Search for "serialisation of `struct`" or similar. That is a standard term.